# What primitive data types are there in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primitive-types

I am a ruby developer who is learning to use python. I am not able to understand the concept of datatypes with python. In ruby there are no primitive data types everything is an object of some class. Like 1,0.3 are objects of Integer class and "string" is an object of String class.

Is it the same with python?

Online documentation for python shows 5 types of primitive data types but how are these stored/used by python and how are methods being called upon these if they are not objects of some class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `1` is example of object of class `int` and `'sometext'` is example of object of class `str`. They have own methods.

What might be confusing there is class named `object` which is parent class for all other classes. Function `isinstance` might be useful for learning about that:

```
print(isinstance('sometext',object)) #True
print(isinstance('sometext',int)) #False
print(isinstance('sometext',str)) #True
```